# CLB adder structure in Xilinx Virtex and adder implementations in VHDL

Tags: sum, addition, vhdl, fpga, xilinx

1-) I am curious about how ISE synthesizer implements adders in Virtex. I mean what is the smallest adder block size in slices? I was searching Xilinx documentations and I came up with this [Virtex-4 FPGA User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug070.pdf)

On page 204 it says, "The arithmetic logic includes an XOR gate that allows a 2-bit full adder to be implemented within a slice.". But there should be carry lookahead implementation. Because critical path increases logarithmic with the input width.

2-) The other question is, I want to implement long signed vector in VHDL. To achieve higher operating frequencies I want to implement two stage pipelined adder. For example:

```
signal a, b, c: signed(63 downto 0);
```

conventional method

```
c <= a + b;
```

What I want to implement

```
signal c_hi : signed(31 downto 0);
signal c_lo : signed(32 downto 0);

process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge (clk) then
       --1st stage
       c_lo <= ('0' & a(31 downto 0)) + ('0' & b(31 downto 0));
       c_hi <= a(63 downto 32) + b(63 downto 32);
      --2nd stage
      c(63 downto 32) <= c_hi(31 downto 0) + (to_signed(0,31) & c_lo(32 downto 32));
      c(31 downto 0) <= c_lo(31 downto 0);
    end if;
end process;
```

But that includes 2x32bit adder + 1x33bit adder. So, what I asking is how can I give the carry out bit of lower addition while summing higher bits?

3-) Is there a way to obtain carry out/overflow bit without increasing width by one.

Comment: I haven't personally tried the adder generator in FloPoCo for a pipelined integer adder,  but you could see this paper [Pipelined FPGA Adders](https://hal-ens-lyon.archives-ouvertes.fr/ensl-00475780v1/document) which is also found on the [FloPoCo](http://flopoco.gforge.inria.fr/) website.

Comment: Your example 2 is not pipelined. Where is your pipeline register? A pipelined Adder uses only 2x 32 bit adders. There is no 33 bit adder.

Comment: Carry out can only be obtained by widening the result. Overflow is calculated from a(63) and b(63) and independent of c(64).

Comment: @Paebbels of course they are in a process. So how could I obtain carry_out of 32th bit without 33bit adder?

Comment: Sorry I meant 32 + 33 bit adder, but definitely not 3 adders ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's a pipelined adder:

```
signal a          : signed(63 downto 0);
signal b          : signed(63 downto 0);
signal c          : signed(64 downto 0);
signal sum_stage1 : unsigned(32 downto 0);

process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    -- stage 1: add first 32 bits
    sum_stage1 <= ('0' & a(31 downto 0)) + ('0' & b(31 downto 0));

    -- stage 2: add next 32 bits (incl. C_in)
    c(31 downto 0)  <= sum_stage1(31 downto 0);   -- optional: align intermediate sums
    c(64 downto 32) <= (32 downto 1 => '0') & sum_stage1(sum_stage1'high) +
                       ('0' & a(63 downto 32)) +
                       ('0' & b(63 downto 32));
  end if;
end process;
```

Step 1: add 32 bits (31..0)
Step 2: add 32 bits (63..32) (incl. C_in; C_in = C_out from step 1)

Minimum resources consumption:

- 2x 32 bit adder or 32 + 33 bit adder if its signed and C_out is relevant
- 33 bit register